# Why cant i access subtype via templates?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, typename

Here is an example. I get an error on `typename T::SubType*` inside of the template but not outside.

using gcc0x i get

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'TemplateBase<A>':
prog.cpp:8:36:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:4:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'
prog.cpp:8:7: error: forward declaration of 'class A'
```

in vs i get some random error msg. Here is the code.

```
template< typename T >
struct TemplateBase {
        void ff() {}
        typename T::SubType*f(){ return 0; }
        //typename T::SubType*f();
};

class A : public TemplateBase< A > {
public:
        //struct SubTypeT {
        struct SubType {
        int i;
        };
        //typedef SubTypeT SubType;
private:
        SubType m;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::SubType*f(){ return 0; }

int main() {
        f<A>();
        A a;
        a.ff();
}
```

Comment: "in vs i get some random error msg" - perhaps random to you, but probably not to us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class is fully defined at the closing brace, not at the point where you're listing its parent classes. Therefore, in `class A : public TemplateBase< A > {`, you're instantiating `TemplateBase` with an incomplete class A.

Comment: Would it be possible to define a function in TemplateBase in some way that uses T::SubType ?

Comment: Yes. Normally, you define a function outside a class; the class only contains the declaration. Then there's obviously no problem. As a shortcut, you're allowed to put the function body inside the class, but it's still compiled as if it were outside (except that functions defined inside the class are implicitly `inline`)

Comment: There's still a problem with the declaration of the function though, i.e. `typename A::SubType`.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I really answered the question in the comment there. You can't _declare_ a function in `TemplateBase<T>` that uses `T::SubType` when `T` is incomplete.

Comment: ok so it isnt possible. darn. I was trying to keep subtype inside of A. I seen an example where SubType is `SomeType<A>{}` specialization and far away in code.

Comment: Well, that's yet another question. E.g. you could define `template<typename U> U* f() { return 0; }` in `TemplateBase<T>`, and then instantiate `TemplateBase<A>::f<A::SubType>` at a point where `A` is complete.